# How to compute a relative date from a given date?

Tags: bash, date, gnu

The GNU `date` command can output date computed from relative items such as `-1 hour` or `1 month ago`. It can also output date from different input format (for instance calendar date, seconds since epoch, etc...).

Is it possible to combine both a date format and a relative time to compute a new date from a given date using the GNU§ `date` utility?

Something like:

```
date_epoch=`date "+%s"`
date --date="@$date_epoch -1 month"
```

The second command gives an "incorrect date" error...

Answer (score 3):

You can do it, sure:

```
$ date -d"$(date -d@$date_epoch) -1 month" "+%Y-%m-%d"
2013-09-16
```

Which comes from:

```
$ date_epoch=$(date "+%s")
$ date -d@$date_epoch
Wed Oct 16 23:46:50 CEST 2013
```

that you can use it "hardcoded":

```
$ date -d"Wed Oct 16 23:46:50 CEST 2013 -1 month"
Mon Sep 16 23:46:50 CEST 2013
```

Or using the variable:

```
$ date -d"$(date -d@$date_epoch) -1 month"
Mon Sep 16 23:46:50 CEST 2013
```

Comment: Ok I think my problem is the output format of the `date -d@$date_epoch` command. I get a french language date such as: "mercredi 16 octobre 2013, 23:11:13 (UTC+0200)" and it seems not to be a valid input format for the second date command. Any idea how get a valid input format? Why does the seconds since epoch format does not directly works?

Comment: Based on http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/58233/how-to-change-the-language-for-date-command, what if you add `LANG=en_US` to the beginning of both `date` commands in the expression?

Comment: Found it! This works: `date -d"$(LC_TIME=C date -d@$date_epoch) -1 month" "+%Y-%m-%d"`. I did not try to change the `LANG` variable but thanks for the help!

Comment: Good! Regarding your second question, I see in `man date` that `-d, --date=STRING`  --> `DATE STRING` `A date string may contain items indicating calendar date, time of day, time zone, day of week, relative time, relative date, and numbers.  An empty string indicates the beginning of the day.`